# Use redirect after content creating and use $node

Tags: 7, forms

I modified my submit handler to be redirected to a "thank you" page after creating some content. So far so good.

But I want to use some data of the node just created, so how can I transfer the `$node`-data of the just created node to my thank you page?

I created a new block to be shown only on the thank you page and I want to show some `$node`-data in my block...

```
function mymodule_block_view($delta = '') {
  switch ($delta) {
    case 'your_block':
      $block['subject'] = 'Share by mail';
      $block['content'] = mymodule_sharebutton();
      break;
  }

  return $block;
}


function mymodule_sharebutton() {
  $output = '<a href="">share</a>';

  return $output;
}
```

I already tried with passing `$node`, `$form`, `$form_state`,... but with no luck.

Comment: To make it simpler when you are redirecting perhaps you could slip in node id as a parameter in the url, say `/thank-you/3` You could use that to do `node_load(nid)` or if you think that url will look ugly you could set nid to a session variable before calling `drupal_redirect` in submit handler and use session variable in thank-you page.

Comment: Oh, I like the sound of that. Let me take a look at this.

Comment: For some reason, there is no `$node` variable in my submithandler function...

Comment: `$form_state` contains `nid`, you need to use that and get `$node` from `node_load()`

Comment: no `$form_state` is loaded in my submithandler :(

Answer (score 0):

Use arg(1); - (nid of the current node) in the hook_block_view and pass it in the link

```
function mymodule_block_view($delta = '') {
  switch ($delta) {
    case 'your_block':
      $nid = arg(1);
      $block['subject'] = 'Share by mail';
      $block['content'] = '<a href="">share?nid='.$nid.'</a>';
      break;
  }
  return $block;
}
```

Once you do that, you can make your thank_you page react on the nid argument by loading the node:

```
$node = node_load($nid);
```

and extracting from it whatever you need